# Speed up graphic drawing pyqtgraph

Tags: python, numba, pyqtgraph

I wonder is there any way to speed up graphics drawing. I use pyqtgraph, but it's still to slow for my case: draw a few lines with several million points.

I read about Numda, but don't fully understand how to use it to draw graphs in pyqt.

Here's the code, that works correctly for less data. But it takes ~30 seconds to draw 2 lines with like million point.

```
import os
import sys
import threading
import time
from functools import partial
from typing import List
from numba import jit

import pandas as pd

try:
    from pyqtgraph import PlotDataItem, PlotWidget, mkPen
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
    from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

    qt_imported = True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    qt_imported = False

    class QDialog:
        pass

    class QCheckBox:
        pass

    class PlotDataItem:
        pass

if not qt_imported:
    def pyqtSignal(s):
        def fake_decorator(fn):
            return fn

        return fake_decorator

    def pyqtSlot(*args):
        def fake_decorator(fn):
            return fn

        return fake_decorator

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Points:
    x: List[float] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])
    y: List = field(default_factory=lambda: [])

@dataclass
class Figure:
    check_box: QCheckBox
    line: PlotDataItem
    data: Points = Points()


COLORS = ["orange", "green", "blue", "red"]


class UfaIkGraphicsWidget(QDialog):
    if qt_imported:
        pass

    def __init__(self, caption, path):
        super().__init__()
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.caption = caption

        self.window_width = 900
        self.window_height = 700
        self.resize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        self.graphWidget = PlotWidget()
        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')
        styles = {"color": "#f00", "font-size": "20px"}
        self.graphWidget.setLabel("left", "y", **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setLabel("bottom", "x, c", **styles)
        self.graphWidget.addLegend()
        self.graphWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.setWindowTitle(caption)

        self.figures = {}

        layout_v = QVBoxLayout()
        color_iterator = 0
        self.choice_buttons = {}

        _, file_extension = os.path.splitext(path)
        data = None
        if file_extension == '.csv':
            data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=path, sep=';', header=None)
        elif file_extension == '.xlsx':
            data = pd.read_excel(io=path)

        channels = data.columns.tolist()[-1] + 1
        values_number = data.index.tolist()[-1] + 1

        for i in range(channels):
            key = f'channel_{i + 1}'

            color = COLORS[color_iterator]

            current_button = QCheckBox(f"{key}")
            current_button.setChecked(True)
            current_style = "QCheckBox::indicator:checked {background-color: " + color + ";}"
            current_button.setStyleSheet(current_style)
            current_button.clicked.connect(partial(self.press_check_box, key))

            pen = mkPen(color=color)

            channel_data = data.iloc[:, i].values.tolist()

            line: PlotDataItem = self.graphWidget.plot(list(range(len(channel_data))), channel_data,
                                                       pen=pen, symbol='o', symbolSize=5,
                                                       symbolBrush=color, skipFiniteCheck=True)

            self.figures[key] = Figure(check_box=current_button, line=line, data=Points())

            color_iterator += 1
            layout_v.addWidget(current_button)

        self.graphWidget.setXRange(0, 10)
        for name in self.figures.keys():
            self.figures[name].line.setClipToView(True)

        false_all = QPushButton('Снять все')
        false_all.clicked.connect(self.change_all_check_boxes_false)
        true_all = QPushButton('Поставить все')
        true_all.clicked.connect(self.change_all_check_boxes_true)
        layout_v.addWidget(true_all)
        layout_v.addWidget(false_all)

        layout_h = QHBoxLayout()
        layout_h.addWidget(self.graphWidget)
        layout_h.addLayout(layout_v)
        self.setLayout(layout_h)

    def change_all_check_boxes_true(self):
        self.change_all_check_boxes(True)

    def change_all_check_boxes_false(self):
        self.change_all_check_boxes(False)

    def change_all_check_boxes(self, is_check: bool):
        for name in self.figures.keys():
            state = self.figures[name].check_box.isChecked()
            if state != is_check:
                self.figures[name].check_box.click()

    def press_check_box(self, name):
        if self.figures[name].check_box.isChecked():
            self.figures[name].line.show()
        else:
            self.figures[name].line.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = UfaIkGraphicsWidget(caption='Тест', path='small_test.csv')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Numba can only speed up codes doing loops on native data types and Numpy arrays. It is not meant to speed up general purpose Python code. Please read the *Numba documentation* (especially the *first page* explaining that). I you want a general purpose JIT, then consider using PyPy. Note that PyPy does not supports all Python modules and it may not be faster regarding the target code. For a code like this, I expect the library to be slow so using another one is certainly the way to go (note this is off topic on StackOverflow).

Comment: I need to use Python not PyPy, this is an important condition.
If numba is not meant for this purpose, what other tools can I use in Python?

Comment: You mean CPython no ? Python is a language, CPython is an implementation (slow standard interpreter) like PyPy is (faster JIT). You need to profile to be sure the slow part is in the plot drawing. If so, then you need to find another library (IDK which one), or to write your own implementation (typically using low-level rendering library combined with Numpy+Numba). Doing this manually is cumbersome and a quite huge work so I do not advise you to do that. If the plotting part is not the bottleneck then please update the question to point which one it is.

Comment: Put it shortly: no tool can automatically speed up a library not written in pure-Python; pure-Python code can generally barely be optimized using embedded JIT. The only efficient general purpose JIT I know is PyPy. In all cases, you need to do a profiling and provide results for more help.